# Можно ли для android написать программу которая показывает данные чужого сайта?

Tags: android

У нас в университетском портале показывает Ф.И.О учителя (и многое) для каждого студента. Студент входит в портал выбирая свой факультет, фамилию и т.д. и вводя свой пароль. Хочу написать программу для андройд 2.3, чтобы один раз вводить пароль и открыв приложению видеть обновленных(!) учителей.... Возможно ли такое, чтобы войти в чужой (университетский) сайт из чужого(своего) приложения? И как решить эту задачу?

Comment: я же студент - откуда у меня денег чтобы нанять кого-нибудь. и вообще-то у меня есть опыт в программирований на си,с# и python, немного

Comment: @Daulet - обычное клиент-серверное приложение. Вам надо посылать POST (GET) запросы на сервер из приложения, и обрабатывать ответы, ровно также, как это делает браузер.

Comment: После входа сохраните куки в приложении, потом при их использовании будете залогиненым пользователем.

Answer (score 4):

> Возможно ли такое, чтобы войти в чужой (университетский) сайт из чужого(своего) приложения?

ну браузер же как-то входит. А браузер - это программа )

> чтобы один раз вводить пароль

никто не мешает запомнить введённые данные

> И как решить эту задачу?

в вашем случае - нанять кого-нибудь )

Answer (score 3):

Библиотека JSOUP значительно упрощает задачу

[пример](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial)